# Quais as medalhas importantes para as eleições?

Tags: debate, eleição

Quais são as medalhas que são usadas para fazer esta estatística?

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Moderação:

- [**Dever Cívico**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty)
  Votou 300 vezes
- [**Eleitorado**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/44/electorate)
  Votou 600 vezes em perguntas, sendo estes pelo menos um quarto do total de votos
- [**Espírito Esportivo**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/sportsmanship)
  Votou a favor de outra resposta em uma pergunta que você respondeu
- [**Representante**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/70/deputy)
  Criou 80 sinalizações úteis
- [**Marechal**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/76/marshal)
  Criou 500 sinalizações úteis
- [**Limpeza**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4/cleanup)
  Reverteu uma edição
- [**Analista**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/78/reviewer)
  Fez 250 análises em uma das filas
- [**Administrador**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/steward)
  Fez 1000 análises em uma das filas

### Edição:

- [**Organizador**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5/organizer)
  Editou tags em uma pergunta
- [**Strunk & White**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white)
  Editou 80 posts
- [**Copidesque**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/49/copy-editor)
  Editou 500 posts de terceiros (sem contar posts removidos e edições de tags)
- [**Intérprete**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/115/explainer)
  Editou e respondeu 1 pergunta (as 2 ações com intervalo de 12 horas; resposta com pontuação positiva)
- [**Aprimorador**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/116/refiner)
  Editou e respondeu 50 perguntas (as 2 ações com intervalo de 12 horas; resposta com pontuação positiva)
- [**Editor de Tags**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/58/tag-editor)
  Editou um Wiki da Tag

### Participação:

- [**Quórum**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/67/quorum)
  1 post com mais de 2 pontos no Meta
- [**Convenção**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/68/convention)
  10 posts com mais de 2 pontos no Meta
- [**Investidor**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/45/investor)
  Ofereceu recompensa na pergunta de outro usuário
- [**Entusiasta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/54/enthusiast)
  Visitou o site 30 dias consecutivos
- [**Constituinte**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/81/constituent)
  Votou durante a fase final de uma eleição
- [**Aniversariante**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling)
  Membro há mais de 1 ano, com pelo menos 200 de reputação

---

As medalhas contam para a pontuação dos candidatos, que é [calculada dessa forma](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252643/175506):

- 1 ponto para cada 1000 de reputação com um limite de 20.000 de reputação, que garantem 20 pontos.
- 1 para cada medalha da lista acima.

Medalhas que podem ser conquistadas mais de uma vez contam apenas uma vez para sua pontuação. A soma de 20 pontos pela reputação mais 20 pontos de medalhas dá o total de 40.

---

No caso do Jorge B., por exemplo:

- 4.512 rep = 4 pontos
- 4 + 4 + 5 medalhas = 13 pontos

Portanto: 17/40 pontos