# O que é pontuação do candidato?

Tags: debate, eleição

Estava olhando os candidatos que concorrem ao cargo de moderador, e percebi que é apresentado uma pontuação do mesmo.

Minha pergunta é: Como é calculado essa pontuação e o que ela influencia na prática? Devo votar ou deixar de votar em alguém baseado em sua pontuação alta ou baixa?

Comment: Veja se responde à sua dúvida: [Quais as medalhas importantes para as eleições?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3907/7210)

Comment: Respondendo à segunda pergunta, a pontuação, na prática serve como um indicador do trabalho do utilizador no site. Sendo que, até 20 pontos é a reputação do utilizador no site adquirida ao perguntar e responder, ou seja, dá para ter uma ideia se é ativo a responder e perguntar. Os restantes 20 pontos advêm de medalhas do site, que dão uma boa indicação sobre o trabalho realizado em moderação, edição e participação. É um bom indicador, claro, mas não o único. Se você conhecer as pessoas pode ter também uma ideia se a pessoa tem a mentalidade que é preciso para moderar o site.

Comment: Mas tem como ver essa pontuação? Tipo supondo que eu queira me candidatar eu posso ver essa pontuação antes?

Comment: @FleuquerLima acho que não, mas se fizeres as contas, como vem no link que te mandei, consegues ter uma noção.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo a resposta do @Gabe na pergunta [Quais as medalhas importantes para as eleições?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3903/quais-as-medalhas-importantes-para-as-elei%C3%A7%C3%B5es/3907#3907) por cada 1000 pontos de reputação você arrecada 1 ponto até ao máximo de 20, os outros pontos podem ser calculados consoante as medalhas que você tiver no momento, basta consultar a lista das medalhas na resposta do @Gabe.

Respondendo à segunda pergunta, a pontuação, na prática serve como um indicador do trabalho do utilizador no site. Sendo que, até 20 pontos é a reputação do utilizador no site adquirida ao perguntar e responder, ou seja, dá para ter uma ideia se é ativo e se coloca bons conteúdos.

Os restantes 20 pontos advêm de medalhas do site, que dão uma boa indicação sobre o trabalho realizado em moderação, edição e participação.

Resumindo, é um bom indicador claro, mas não o único. Podes ver também as análises e os posts no meta para ter uma noção se o candidato se interessa pelos assuntos em discussão sobre o site e a forma como intervém nos mesmos.

Além disso, se você conhecer as pessoas pode ter também uma ideia se a pessoa tem a mentalidade/capacidade que é preciso para moderar o site.

O que eu acho é que se deve analisar como um todo para ter uma ideia mais assertiva sobre em quem vamos votar. Votar em consciência é sempre melhor, aqui ou em qualquer lado que se tenha de eleger alguém.

Comment: Boca de urna, boca de urna! :D

Comment: @bigown não vale usar expressões que não conheço ;) Tive de ir pesquisar :D

Comment: Só zuando... https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boca_de_urna